# Compressing A Series of JSON Objects While Maintaining Serial Reading?

Tags: python, json, file-io, compression, zlib

I have a bunch of *json objects* that I need to compress as it's eating too much disk space, approximately `20 gigs` worth for a few million of them.

Ideally what I'd like to do is compress each individually and then when I need to read them, just iteratively load and decompress each one. I tried doing this by creating a text file with each line being a compressed *json object* via *zlib*, but this is failing with a

`decompress error due to a truncated stream`,

which I believe is due to the compressed strings containing new lines.

Anyone know of a good method to do this?

Comment: Show minimal code reproducing the problem.  You're "doing something wrong", but too hard to *guess* without seeing what you've done.

Comment: Compressing them individually is going to reduce the potential space savings from compression.

Comment: Do you require random access to the objects, or will you be reading them sequentially?

Comment: I don't require random access, just need sequential.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use a [`gzip.GzipFile()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) and treat it like a regular file; write JSON objects line by line, and read them line by line.

The object takes care of compression transparently, and will buffer reads, decompressing chucks as needed.

```
import gzip
import json

# writing
with gzip.GzipFile(jsonfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for obj in objects:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(obj) + '\n')

# reading
with gzip.GzipFile(jsonfilename, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        # process obj
```

This has the added advantage that the compression algorithm can make use of repetition *across* objects for compression ratios.

Comment: Or `bz2.BZ2File` since 2.3, or `lzma.LZMAFile` since 3.3.

Comment: Worked great! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: If the application that's going to catch these files is expecting json, though, this won't work without massaging of the sort Martijn provides with his reading method. Ie an application expecting raw json will be disappointed.

Comment: @duhaime: of course! Producing compressed JSON is an exception, not a usual case. When exchanging JSON over HTTP, the HTTP server may still apply content compression transparently, but you'd leave that to your HTTP library to handle (`requests` does this for you, for example).

Comment: in Python 3 you may have to convert the json string to bytes (like `json_str.encode()`), as the gzip.GzipFile handler expects to write a bytes-like object, not 'str'.

Comment: @YiboYang or just wrap the `outfile` object in an [`io.TextIOWrapper` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try an incremental json parser, such as [jsaone](http://pietrobattiston.it/jsaone).

That is, create a *single* json with all your objects, and parse it like

```
with gzip.GzipFile(file_path, 'r') as f_in:
    for key, val in jsaone.load(f_in):
        ...
```

This is quite similar to Martin's answer, wasting slightly more space but maybe slightly more comfortable.

*EDIT:* oh, by the way, it's probably fair to clarify that I wrote jsaone.