# Python 3, read/write compressed json objects from/to gzip file

Tags: json, python-3.x, gzip

For Python3, I followed [@Martijn Pieters's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449625/python-compressing-a-series-of-json-objects-while-maintaining-serial-reading) with this:

```
import gzip
import json

# writing
with gzip.GzipFile(jsonfilename, 'w') as fout:
    for i in range(N):
        uid = "whatever%i" % i
        dv = [1, 2, 3]
        data = json.dumps({
            'what': uid,
            'where': dv})

        fout.write(data + '\n')
```

but this results in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
  File "C:\Users\Think\my_json.py", line 118, in write_json
    fout.write(data + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\Think\Anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 258, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any thoughts about what is going on?

Comment: The code was probably written with python2 in mind. Try to encode the data: `(data+'\n').encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Nope, same error.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You have four steps of transformation here.

1. a Python data structure (nested dicts, lists, strings, numbers, booleans)
2. a Python string containing a serialized representation of that data structure ("JSON")
3. a list of bytes containing a representation of that string ("UTF-8")
4. a list of bytes containing a - shorter - representation of that previous byte list ("gzip")

So let's take these steps one by one.

```
import gzip
import json

data = []
for i in range(N):
    uid = "whatever%i" % i
    dv = [1, 2, 3]
    data.append({
        'what': uid,
        'where': dv
    })                                           # 1. data

json_str = json.dumps(data) + "\n"               # 2. string (i.e. JSON)
json_bytes = json_str.encode('utf-8')            # 3. bytes (i.e. UTF-8)

with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'w') as fout:       # 4. fewer bytes (i.e. gzip)
    fout.write(json_bytes)
```

Note that adding `"\n"` is completely superfluous here. It does not break anything, but beyond that it has no use. I've added that only because you have it in your code sample.

Reading works exactly the other way around:

```
with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'r') as fin:        # 4. gzip
    json_bytes = fin.read()                      # 3. bytes (i.e. UTF-8)

json_str = json_bytes.decode('utf-8')            # 2. string (i.e. JSON)
data = json.loads(json_str)                      # 1. data

print(data)
```

Of course the steps can be combined:

```
with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
```

and

```
with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'r') as fin:
    data = json.loads(fin.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: @Tomalak is it compulsory to convert the JSON file into a string then in bytes for compression? Will conversion time should be counted in case comparing 2 different compression methods?I might be missing basics of compression but still wanted to know the answer.

Comment: @ranadan You can compress any stream of bytes. How you end up with a stream of bytes is entirely up to you. Converting a Python data structure to JSON (*serializing* it as JSON) is one way to make it into a stream of bytes. There might be other serializers, JSON just happens to be an extremely common one. [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) is a Python-specific serializer that turns Python objects into a stream of bytes. If you don't intend to share data across different environments, a platform-specific serializer might be the better choice.

Comment: @Tomalak So when I am comparing 2 different compression methods with respect to time. I should account the time I take to convert the JSON into bytes as it is part of compression??.

Comment: @Tomalak see this once. [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306084/comprising-different-compressing-methods-for-json-data-in-python3) . For me i am using JSON only and trying to compare different compression methods with respect to time and space.

Comment: That's a rather subjective question. If you see "getting an object from memory to a compressed file" as a single operation, then yes. In effect you are not really trying to measure the performance of the zip algorithm, or are you?

Comment: @Tomalak yes i am trying to measure the performance of zip algorithm. I have JSON  data which i have to send to the server. For which I usually gzip and send the data. But I want to check actual performance on which i will choose any of the compression algorithm.
one more thing for converting and existing JSON file to bytes is there a better way than this?
`with open('data.json','r') as fid_json:
        # get json as type dict
        json_dict = json.load(fid_json)
        # convert dict to str
        json_str = str(json_dict)`

Comment: When you already have JSON why would you want parse and serialize it again? (Rhetorical question, don't answer it. Think about it instead.)

Comment: This has an event more compact approach that lets gzip handle the encoding and json uses the stream from gzip directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535758/1236083

Comment: we can simplify the final example further with `json.load` instead of `loads` as just `data = json.load(fin)`

Comment: True, `json.load` can (as of Python 3.6) deal with byte input. But it lacks a way of specifying the encoding and assumes a default instead. Since explicit is better than implicit, I prefer specifying the encodings myself. (Also I wanted to keep it equivalent to the longer sample above.)

Comment: I am making some test. `"\n"` does something if `data` is a dictionary with many dictionaries in it. In particular it successively allows to read the file line by line. Is that possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as line-wise reading of JSON. You can have a file format that has one JSON-encoded entity per line, but that file *itself* is not JSON anymore.

Comment: @greenie-beans Whatever `json.dumps` does is not related to gzip at all. I would suggest to make a short code sample (only the `json` part of the code, nothing else) which reproduces the error you see, and ask that as a stand-alone question.

Comment: @greenie-beans Never mind, you got it solved, that's the important part. Comments can be deleted. :)

Comment: Just curious: Why did you use the `GzipFile` class directly instead of using [the `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open)?

Comment: @Harm Hm... I guess it didn't occur to me at the time. :)

Comment: @Tomalak No worries, just thought it looks cleaner, mirroring [the regular `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 42):

The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49535758/1236083) (thanks, @Rafe) has a big advantage: as encoding is done on-the-fly, you don't create two complete, intermediate string objects of the generated json. With big objects, this saves memory.

```py
with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'wt', encoding='UTF-8') as zipfile:
    json.dump(data, zipfile)
```

In addition, reading and decoding is simple as well:

```py
with gzip.open(jsonfilename, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as zipfile:
    my_object = json.load(zipfile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Explosion (makers of Spacy) maintains a package called 'srsly' for serializing different file types. They don't advertise it much, but it's really useful.

Writting to GZIP:

```py
import srsly

data = {"foo": "bar", "baz": 123}
srsly.write_gzip_json("/path/to/file.json.gz", data)
```

Reading GZIP:

```py
data = srsly.read_gzip_json("/path/to/file.json.gz")
```

You can read more on their pypi page: https://pypi.org/project/srsly/

Comment: One of the awesome packages. I was searching for JSON compression

Answer (score 0):

In order to write to a `json.gz`, you can use the following snippet:

```
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("file_path_to_write", "wt") as f:
        json.dump(expected_dict, f)
```

And to read from a `json.gz`, you can use the following snippet:

````
import json
import gzip

with gzip.open("file_path_to_read", "rt") as f:
        expected_dict = json.load(f)
```
````