# Comprising different compressing methods for JSON data in python3

Tags: python, json, compression, gzip

So, I want to compress my JSON data using different compressor. I used this to compress the JSON.

```
import gzip
import JSON

with gzip.GzipFile('2.json', 'r') as isfile:
    for line in isfile:
        obj = json.loads(line)
```

which raises error.

```
raise OSError('Not a gzipped file (%r)' % magic)

OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'[\n')
```

I also tried direct compressing using.

```
zlib_data= zlib.compress(data)
```

which raises an error.

```
return lz4.block.compress(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

So, Basically i want to compress a JSON using all the methods and to compute the time taken for the compression in different methods.

Comment: Is `2.json` a gzipped file? What does ` (b'[\n')` mean in the error you state?  What is `data` in the next attempt you mention? (The error suggests it's a list and a bytes-like object is required)

Comment: @doctorlove No, 2.json is a simple JSON file. and the next attempt data is this.
`with open('2.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)`

where again 2.JSON is a simple JSON file.

Comment: Given that you compress and uncompress some JSON, could you show **how** you create these files?

Comment: @MSeifert This is a sample JSON file which i downloaded from internet. Should I post the structure? Thing is since it's a simple JSON(text) it should compress. what's the better way to do it?

Comment: The problem is that I can't reproduce the exception currently. So it's hard/impossible for anyone to debug this issue. Having a sample that reproduces the issue (without downloading anything from the internet) would be favorite.

Comment: @MSeifert I can understand, and I have no idea why it doesn't reproduce the exception. I have attached a sample in the link please have a look.
[URL](https://paste.ofcode.org/k9FM24nGEwCJJWeQzHmCjU)

Comment: @MSeifert any help?

Comment: As I said: Something that I don't have to download would be favorite. :) Call me old-fashioned but I don't trust zipped downloadable files from unknown persons.

Comment: @MSeifert there is nothing to download in the link. it's just pasted JSON which you can copy and save in a file. :) Apart from that if you can normally suggest other way to compress a JSON and to calculate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### On python2.7

it seems to be a problem of the type of your data

**the data to compress should be a 'str' type**

```
import gzip
import json
import lz4
import time

with gzip.GzipFile('data.gz','w') as fid_gz:
    with open('data.json','r') as fid_json:
        # get json as type dict
        json_dict = json.load(fid_json)
        # convert dict to str
        json_str = str(json_dict)
    # write string
    fid_gz.write(json_str)

# check well maded
with gzip.GzipFile('data.gz','r') as fid_gz :
    print(fid_gz.read())
```

even if gzip compression

```
gzip.zlib.compress(json_str,9)
```

even if lz4 compression

```
lz4.block.compress(json_str)
```

and time checking would be

```
# set start time
st = time.time()
# calculate elasped time
print(time.time() - st)
```

---

## On python3.5

the difference between python2.7 and python 3 is the type of your data to compress

**the data to compress should be a 'byte' type via bytes()**

when making a .gz file

```
with gzip.GzipFile('data.gz','w') as fid_gz:
    with open('data.json','r') as fid_json:
        json_dict = json.load(fid_json)
        json_str = str(json_dict)
        # bytes(string, encoding)
        json_bytes = bytes(json_str,'utf8')
    fid_gz.write(json_bytes)
```

or just compress with gzip.compress(data, compresslevel=9)

```
# 'data' takes bytes
gzip.compress(json_bytes)
```

or just compress with zlib.compress(bytes, level=-1, /)

```
gzip.zlib.compress(json_bytes,9)
```

or just compress with lz4.bloc.compress(source, compression=0)

```
# 'source' takes both 'str' and 'byte'
lz4.block.compress(json_str)
lz4.block.compress(json_bytes)
```

the measuring time is on your intention.

cheers

Comment: what is '9' in the `gzip.zlib.compress(json_str,9)` i tried that and it still gives the error. `gzip.zlib.compress(json_str,9)

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: it's compression level,
`gzip.zlib.compress()`
`compress(string[, level]) -- Returned compressed string`
but on python2.7, I'm trying python3 now

Comment: so why is it giving error. it seems to work with `lz4.block.compress(json_str)` . look at the error once. Is it compulsory to convert it in string before compression? As i am trying to compare the time taken to compress. it must be taking some time to convert it into dictionary and then string.

Comment: yeah compression works. but the thing is, it's absolute compulsory to convert the JSON as the output type is also bytes. And second can't I measure the execution time of just `gzip.compress(json_bytes)` ?. Your answer helped a lot thanks.

Comment: `st = time.time()
gzip.compress(json_bytes)
print(time.time()-st)`
this may help you

Comment: one last thing. as i am trying to write back the bytes to JSON. till converting string it's fine. lastly it gives error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`. so can you just help with this as i want the compressed file in JSON.