# Compressing a list of json as Gzip using a file object

Tags: python, json, gzip

I have to compress the list of dictionary using gzip and send as request parameter to a backend API. While using the gzip library i couldn't send the json because everytime I get a bad request from the server. Here is an example of the data:

```
[{'name':'John'}, {'name': 'Clark'}]
```

First I tried using the version 1 of the code below but I always get a

> TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'

So, I tried version 2 which returns a bad request.There is another similar answer but I need to do this with a file-object. Could you point out where I am going wrong?

> Version 1

```
import gzip 
import json
import io

inp1 = {"name": "John"}
inp2 = {"name": "Clark"}
final_inp = []
final_inp.append(inp1)
final_inp.append(inp2)
print(final_inp)

data = json.dumps(final_inp)
out = io.StringIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
    f.write(data)
    res = out.getvalue()

print(res)
```

> Version 2

```
# same imports and declartion from version 1
# this code works but i have to do it using version 1.
data = json.dumps(final_inp)
out = io.BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="wb") as f:
    f.write(data.encode())
    res = out.getvalue()

print(res)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3, read/write compressed json objects from/to gzip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450065/python-3-read-write-compressed-json-objects-from-to-gzip-file)

Comment: @AMC the answer in that link uses a file, but i have to do it using a file-object.