# How to combine a string of multiple json gz files in a list into one json gz file then open the file?

Tags: python, json

I have a list of json gz https files

FYI: these files are not real files due to privacy laws but mimic the exact structure.

```
list_of_files = ['https://premera.saph.com/202011/json.gz', 'https://premera.saph.com/202011/json.gz']
```

My goal is to combine all these json gz files into one large json gz file.

I've tried numerous ways to do this by referencing other Stack Overflow questions; however, I am unable to find exactly what I am looking for.

This comment helped me somewhat, but in my situation, I believe that I need to add requests to get the file since it is an http.

[Python 3, read/write compressed json objects from/to gzip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450065/python-3-read-write-compressed-json-objects-from-to-gzip-file)

```
import requests
import gzip

one_file = file[0]

with open(one_file, 'rb') as f:
     serial = gzip.decompress(f.read())
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://premera.saph.com/202011/json.gz'
```

Got this error on the correct https since this is changed for privacy.

Comment: can you provide a cleaner code ? here list_of_files is not used and file doesn't exist

Comment: You'll need to download the file first before you can decompress it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This comment helped me somewhat, but in my situation, I believe that I
> need to add requests to get the file since it is an http.

Indeed built-in `open` function does not support HTTP access, however in this case I would use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen), consider following example using [example file provided by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/File:Example.json.gz)

```
import json
import gzip
import urllib.request
url = "https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/f/ff/Example.json.gz"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as gzf:
    with gzip.open(gzf) as jsonf:
        data = json.load(jsonf)
        print(data)
```

gives output

```
{'InstallTime': '1295768962', 'Comments': 'Will test without extension.', 'Theme': 'classic/1.0', 'Version': '4.0b10pre', 'id': 'ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384', 'Vendor': 'Mozilla', 'EMCheckCompatibility': 'false', 'Throttleable': '1', 'Email': 'deinspanjer@mozilla.com', 'URL': 'http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/entry/the_shit_finally_hits_the', 'version': '4.0b10pre', 'CrashTime': '1295903735', 'ReleaseChannel': 'nightly', 'submitted_timestamp': '2011-01-24T13:15:48.550858', 'buildid': '20110121153230', 'timestamp': 1295903748.551002, 'Notes': 'Renderers: 0x22600,0x22600,0x20400', 'StartupTime': '1295768964', 'FramePoisonSize': '4096', 'FramePoisonBase': '7ffffffff0dea000', 'AdapterRendererIDs': '0x22600,0x22600,0x20400', 'Add-ons': 'compatibility@addons.mozilla.org:0.7,enter.selects@agadak.net:6,{d10d0bf8-f5b5-c8b4-a8b2-2b9879e08c5d}:1.3.3,sts-ui@sidstamm.com:0.1,masspasswordreset@johnathan.nightingale:1.04,support@lastpass.com:1.72.0,{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}:4.0b10pre', 'BuildID': '20110121153230', 'SecondsSinceLastCrash': '810473', 'ProductName': 'Firefox', 'legacy_processing': 0}
```

Explanation: first with does open file under specified URL then `gzip.open` is used to decompress is, so `json.load` can be used to parse JSON and get data (data is `dict`). Note that all used `import`s pertain to standard library, so you do not need to install any external package.

Comment: and if you wanted to iterate through the list of files: Would you do this? 


```For i in url: 
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as gzf:
         with gzip.open(gzf) as jsonf:
                data = json.load(jsonf)
                print(data)
```

Comment: @Zane in such case encase that part in `for url in urls:` so `url` pertains to element of list and `urls` is `list` of `str`s

Answer (score 0):

Assuming list_of_files = file

You are string to decompress a string, what you need to do is download the content of the url and after that you will be able to decompress it.

```py
import requests

list_of_file_content = []
list_of_files = ['https://premera.saph.com/202011/json.gz', 'https://premera.saph.com/202011/json.gz']

for file in list_of_files:
    r = requests.get(file)
    list_of_file_content.append(r.content)
```